# Window does not resize properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently facing the following issues:
 - I'm unable to re-size my window as the elements keep getting out of the panel
 - I cannot center the container in the middle of the page (too much white space on the sides)

How do I fix these problems?

Here is an example of my issue: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krcdyt9f/)

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="contactContainer center-block">

    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="page-header">
                <h1><strong>Contact Information</strong></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body"> 

                <p>For <strong>Employer Services</strong>, kindly contact our Corporate Accounts Team in Singapore:</p><br>

                <p><strong>dork.career Pte Ltd</strong></p>

                <p>10 ubi crescent ubi techpark <br>
                   #03-59 singapore 408564<br><br>
                   Tel:+65 6749 1829<br>
                   Fax: +65 6749 1278<br>
                   Email: info@ideas.sg <br><br>
                </p>

                <img class="contactImg" src="image/contact.png" width="40%"> 

            </div> <!-- end panel body -->

        </div> <!-- end panel panel-default -->

    </div> <!-- end col-lg-8 -->

</div> <!-- end container 2 -->
```

This is my CSS code:

```
    /*
contact page 
*/

.contactImg {
    margin-left:35%;
    margin-top:-35%;
}

.contactContainer {
    display:block;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-family: baskerville old face;
    padding-top:3%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
}

.container2 {
    display:block;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-family: baskerville old face;
    padding-top:3%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
}

.col-lg-8 {
    margin-left:15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margin-left: 15%; allows to add width with the width col-lg-8 calculate it by bootstrap css as user3803747 says that margin-left makes the difference.